Run Zephyr on Spike (riscv -isa-ism)
I been reading about Zephyr for few days. It seems to provide the qemu rv32/rv64 support, like I can run tests straight forward.
But I was wondering is there any way I can try out zephyr's tests on Spike? I mean its pretty standard RISCV ISA simulator, why would zephyr not seems to have anything related to it?
Is there something that I missed to check, please let me know.
Thanks!

Generally, for targeting simulator environments like Spike, Zephyr will define a board and possibly an SoC for the simulator and you would just compile your project for that board (as has been done for QEMU and native sim).
While not in mainline, there is an oldish PR that adds support for Spike as a board and SoC: https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/pull/72682
You might be able to adapt this work, otherwise would have to define these things yourself using Zephyrs Porting Guides.
As to why there's nothing there now, I don't know enough about RISC-V simulators to know which is best but the PR suggests the currently supported QEMU is sufficient for most things.
